# MFC - in child: get notified when parent received WM_ACTIVATE message

Tags: mfc

Is it possible for a child control to get informed if the active state of the parent was child? Without implementing anything at the parent?

Somethig like ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT???

Comment: There are ways, but why does the child window care?

Answer (score 2):

No. Reflection works only for messages sent to the parent **for the control** that are usually captured by the parent. AFAIK this way is also only implemented for WM_COMMAND and WM_NOTIFY messages.

But what is the problem when you just forward the message to the child control.
Another way would be a classic generic subclass that may help you to capture the WM_ACTIVATE message.

Sometimes a timer does the same job, that just checks the current state of the application.

Depends on what you want to do...